# Is the NVP (Nickelodeon Valuable Player) a legitimate award?

Tags: nfl

[Pro Football Reference](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/T/TrubMi00.htm) recognizes Mitch Tribusky as the 2021 NVP and Dak Prescott as the [2022 NVP](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/P/PresDa01.htm).

Is the NVP (Nickelodeon Valuable Player) a legitimate award recognized by the NFL?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an award like the MVP, or Walter Payton. It's a gimmick award from the Nickelodeon network, voted by the fans.

Answer (score -1):

While it's not an award that bears true merit, it is recognized by the NFL. In the past, the best player has not won the NVP (Nickelodeon Valuable Player), but rather the fan favorite.